# How to style Excel sheet in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, export, export-to-excel

I am trying to export the list using export to excel option.

I want to style the excel sheet (Bold the header, Apply background color) while download itself.

How to apply styling to the file downloaded using "Export to excel"?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to customize SharePoint out of the box export to excel functionality in SharePoint online.

So, you cannot add any styling to the excel sheet while downloading it.

---

**Additional**:

You might need to develop custom solution for this using [SharePoint framework list view command set](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api).

Something similar to this sample: [SPFx Export Selected Items to Excel - ListView Command Set](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/main/samples/js-command-selecteditems-export)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If styling is important, then there is no need to start from scratch with "Export to Excel" each time you want a current version of the data in Excel.

When you export a list view to Excel, what happens is that a .qry file is generated, downloaded, and opened in Excel. You can style this Excel file manually as desired and then let people use that workbook instead of starting with "Export to Excel". Refresh the data query in Excel to get the latest data from SharePoint.

As an alternative to the legacy .qry file, Excel can also use Power Query to access the SharePoint data and present it in a styled sheet.